# javascript calling nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm new to coding and trying to figure out nested javascript functions.  I've searched other questions but still can't figure it out.  I'd like a function that takes a string of numbers seperated by spaces, converts the string to an array, and then outputs the result of a mathematical function on the array.

I've written something using the following outline and it works, but seems messy and don't know that I am really doing it the best way. I don't really understand how to call a function from another function.

```
    function doMathOnThisString(string) {
        var ar = convertStringToArray(string);
        return doMathOnArray(ar);

        function convertStringToArray(string) {
            //code that converts the original input string to an array
            return (ar)
        };

        function doMathOnArray(a) {
            //code that does math on an array
        }; 
}
```

Comment: Change `return (ar)` to return the result of the function.

Comment: `var result = string.split(' ').reduce((a,v)=> a * v);` math function goes inside the "reduce"...see details on how reduce works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing just fine with what you have, just take it a step further and you'd be fine. Kindly see my solution below:

```js
function doMathOnThisString(string) {
  // Converts a string of numbers separated by spaces to an array
  function convertStringToArray(input) {
    return input.split(' '); // split input on spaces
  };

  // Sums up the value in the array of number string
  function doMathOnArray(numbersString) {
    return numbersString
      .map((number) => Number(number)) // Convert each (string) number to a proper number
      .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr); // Add each number
  };
  
  
  var stringNumberArray = convertStringToArray(string);
  return doMathOnArray(stringNumberArray);
}

const result = doMathOnThisString('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8');
console.log(result);
```